# Ionic Cordova PhotoGallery SaveImage can't get permission

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-permissions, photolibrary

I'm building an app with ionic & cordova and I have to display some images and let the user decide which to download to its device.

The code I use to save the image is the following:

```
this.pl.requestAuthorization().then(()=>{
    this.pl.saveImage(path+"&ext=.jpg","ALBUM").then(()=>{
        this.showAlert("SUCCESS","Image saved");
    }).catch((err)=>{
        this.showAlert("ERROR",err);
    });
});
```

Explaination:
`this.pl` is the object which refers to the PhotoGallery which is imported in the `constructor` like every other "import"

`this.showAlert` is just a function to alert the user

`path` is the remote URL from the website i show images from, it's something like [this](https://example.com/folder/image.jpg)

This code above always return error: no permission.

I already put the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the AndroidManifest.xml and also tried to ask permission from the [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/), but it didn't work anyway. While using the app, I was asked (only the first time) to acconsent to write access, but no action is ever taken.

Any help?